# Using custom validation attributes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, validationattribute

I'm trying to create a custom validation attribute to apply it. I was using the tutorial: http://ezzylearning.com/tutorial/creating-custom-validation-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc (didn't implement the client side validation. Everything before the client side section). And the IsValid method is never called. All the basic [Required] attributes are working properly, but the custom is initialized only and then ignored.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RequiredIfNotAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object InvalidValue { get; set; }

    static RequiredIfNotAttribute()
    {
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredIfNotAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
    }

    public RequiredIfNotAttribute(String propertyName, Object invalidValue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        InvalidValue = invalidValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        ValidationResult result1 = IsValid(value, context);
        result1.ErrorMessage = "TEST";
        return result1;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The model is using the attribute.

```
 [Display(Name = "Xxxxx")]
 [RequiredIfNot("B", "")]
 public string A { get; set; }
```

And the UI looks as the example

```
<div>
     @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.A)<br />
     @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.A)<br />
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.A)
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please share your controller method's code?

Comment: Start by deleting your `static RequiredIfNotAttribute(){ ... }` code. Not only is it not required, it makes no sense because its not a `RequiredAttributeAdapter`. And your `ValidationResult result1 = IsValid(value, context);` code in the `IsValid()` method makes no sense